# How to preform all valid calculations with a set number of identical values in python?

Tags: python, math, iteration

I need to do all calculations with 4 integers that are identical.For example.

```
def all_math(number,goal):
     "not sure what to put here yet"

>>print(all_math(3, 6)
3+3+3+3
3+3+3-3#<<Should return this
3+3-3-3
3-3-3-3
((3/3)+3)-3
3*3*3*3
```

And so on.

How can I iterate through all of these calculations until I reach a given value (parameter `goal`)?

Comment: What given value? Do you have any extra condition on the possible operations?

Comment: you need to iterate through all permutation of operators to find the result.

Comment: Similar to the countdown maths game?

Comment: What have you tried? The difficulty faced by anyone trying to answer is that we don't know whether you're completely ignorant of Python, or whether you almost know what you're doing but you have one small problem. If you're completely ignorant then the question is too broad, if your real problem is not too broad then narrow it :-)

Comment: Are you required to use four copies of your number? Can you parenthesize arbitrarily, or is it always evaluated from the left (with parentheses only needed to override the normal order of operations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should do it. In case I forgot one option, it should not be difficult to add it:

```
import itertools

def all_math(n, goal):
    operators = ["+" , "-", "*", "/"]
    brackets = ["{0}{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}",
                "({0}{1}{0}){2}{0}{3}{0}",
                "{0}{1}{0}{2}({0}{3}{0})",
                "({0}{1}{0}){2}({0}{3}{0})",
                "({0}{1}{0}{2}{0}){3}{0}",
                "({0}{1}({0}{2}{0})){3}{0}",
                "(({0}{1}{0}){2}{0}){3}{0}",
                "{0}{1}({0}{2}{0}{3}{0})",
                "{0}{1}({0}{2}({0}{3}{0}))",
                "{0}{1}(({0}{2}{0}){3}{0})",
                ]
    for combination in itertools.product(operators, repeat=3):
        for bracket in brackets:
            formula = bracket.format(n, *combination)
            try:
                result = eval(formula)
                print formula + " = " + str(result) #for verification
                if result == goal:
                    return bracket.format(int(n), *combination) #to output integer
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print formula + " = Zero Division Error"

print "Result:", all_math(3.0, 6)
```

If someone has a nice algorithm for the brackets, I'd like to read it. My version is a bit handmade...

**Important note**: Use a float as parameter (`3.0`, not `3`), otherwise you are running into trouble...

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for, but this program doesn't use all the pairings of numbers.For example, it will never reach (3*3)+(3*3)

Comment: well, in fact it does evaluate this specific one since multiplication is performed prior to addition, but in general you are right... Let's see if I find a few minutes to produce an update.
BTW: Is Geocaching involved? Sounds a bit like a Mysti

Comment: This one does the trick. If you have questions about a line, let me know. I can explain or comment as needed. it should not be difficult to change the print-line to collect the results needed in the desired format.

Comment: Last edit to reflect changes in function call. If you wat to get rid of the verification printouts, just remove the print statement.

Comment: Downvote for building string expressions and using `eval`. This can be solved in a more readable, fast and simple way by simply using the `operator` functions directly; you could for example do something like `def expression(n): return lambda a,b,c,d: a(n, b(n, c(n, d(n))))`, assign that to a variable and call it with all combinations of operators.

Comment: yes, I did not think about operator functions which would make it faster (irrelevant in this case) and would allow me to get rid of eval, but your proposed solution misses several combinations (at least if my brains are not suffering from lack of coffee too much) since you can not have pair-wise combinations. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

There are only two fundamentally different ways to build up an expression with four initial values. You can combine the four values in two pairs and then combine the results (three operations in total), or you can combine two, then the result with the third, then the result of that with the last (also three operations). There are sub-cases of the latter according to whether you put each new "original" value on the left or the right: `((3/3)/3)/3` isn't the same as `3/(3/(3/3))` or `3/((3/3)/3)` or `(3/(3/3))/3`.

Then you have to define what binary operations are relevant. You've listed addition, subtraction, multiplication, division. What else? Exponentiation? The other kind of division (integer vs. float)? modulus? `math.atan2`?

This is enough information to exhaustively produce all possibilities (well, if you can do the relevant combinatorics it is). Each pattern only has three places to slot in an operator, so there are `5 * N**3` possibilities where `N` is the number of operators. I doubt that this is a stupidly huge number.

However, you need to decide whether pairs of results that are "equivalent" should both be included in the results or not. For example, do you want to separately list `(3 + 3) * (3 - 3)` and `(3 - 3) * (3 + 3)`? What about `((3 + 3) + 3) + 3)` and `(3 + 3) + (3 + 3)`? What about `3+3+3-3` and `3-3+3+3`? Trimming the output on this basis may be quite difficult if it is necessary, it depends what you consider equivalent and this is not defined in the question.

You also need to decide whether or not to include expressions that cannot be evaluated, such as `(3 - 3) / (3 - 3)`. Identifying these should not be difficult -- if all else fails just evaluate the expression and catch exceptions.

Finally, you need to decide whether or not you have to remove unnecessary parentheses from your output, according to the associativity rules of the operations you're including. Your example output `3+3+3+3` suggests that you would, but `((3/3)+3)-3` suggests you wouldn't.

Comment: I am only interested in finding a combination that equals a given value.If I find one, I will be happy.As for types of operators, I am also using factorial, square root,  3^3(but no new numbers are allowed, so no cubing or squaring other than using one of the four numbers).